# Plugin wrapper not linking

Tags: plugins, wrapper, icloud

My app was created in Unity for Mac and iOS using C#. I have also created an Apple TV version, but need to connect to iCloud for the save since that seems to be the only way to save on that medium. I created a plugin along with a wrapper to link it to the C# project but I am getting an xCode error:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Expanding the debug info, it was the iCloud Wrapper causing the problem, stating there were "Undefined Symbols".

Here's the wrapper code:

```
// CloudKitWrapper.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CloudKitWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void initCloudKit();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void performCloudKitOperation();

    public static void InitCloudKit()
    {
#if UNITY_TVOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
        initCloudKit();
#endif
    }

    public static void PerformCloudKitOperation()
    {
#if UNITY_TVOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
        performCloudKitOperation();
#endif
    }
}

And the Plugin:

CloudKitPlugin.h
@import Foundation
@import CloudKit

@interface CloudKitPlugin : NSObject

+ (void)initCloudKit;
+ (void)performSomeCloudKitOperation;

@end

And:

CloudKitPlugin.m

#import "CloudKitPlugin.h"

@implementation CloudKitPlugin

+ (void)initCloudKit {
#import "CloudKitPlugin.h"
  let cloudStoreLocation = URL(fileURLWithPath: “iCloud.com.BevvyOfFun.LandonsHopeQuest”)
    let cloudStoreDescription =
   NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: cloudStoreLocation)
    cloudStoreDescription.configuration = "Cloud"
cloudStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: “com.BevvyOfFun.LandonsHopeQuest.container”)
     let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptions()
    try? container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: options)
return container
}

+ (void)performCloudKitOperation {
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
   let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: “iCloud.com.BevvyOfFun.LandonsHopeQuest”)
    
   container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { })
    
    let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptions()
    try? container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: options)
            
    return container
}()

}

@end
if(container != null)
{
container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: options)
return container
}


I'd appreciate any help you can give to solve this problem.  Thanks!
```

This wouldn't run on xCode since the wrapper could not link to the plugin.